# Blacklist [excel-macro]

Tags: support, tag-block-request

Please blacklist the tag [excel-macro](/questions/tagged/excel-macro).  Posters should use the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) and [macros](/questions/tagged/macros) tags instead.  I've already cleaned up the tag.

Comment: Why is it better to use two tags versus one tag?

Comment: @Dori Because questions tagged `word` and `macros` may also be relevant to someone posting about excel macros, and the tag system is meant to find relevant posts.  Also, few people are going to know to search for `excel-macro` - but they will search for `excel macro`