# How many suggestions are too many for the mods/approvers?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, moderation

Based on the flow from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138044/179372) and [this answer to it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138048/179372), if I see a particular trend that I feel needs to be edited, and I don't have the privileges required to just edit outright, at what point does it become a bother/burden to the mods/suggestion reviewers?

I've already seen [Robert Harvey's take](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116555/179372) on some edits (as well as others in that link), but is there a general limit? I imagine this answer can vary greatly from one user to the next, but if there's a personal limit I can set for myself to make everyone else happier, I'd be glad to oblige.

Adding to the question from [an FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/179372), perhaps is does not matter how an approver feels about it, rather the system limitation on approvals should be taken into consideration.

In either case, is there any problem (or at the very least, annoyance) with taking it upon myself to go on an edit suggestion spree?

Comment: What are you going to change?

Comment: @RobertHarvey In this instance, though this is not the only time this question would apply, I'd be looking at the [tag:macro] tag applied to [tag:VBA] questions.

Comment: I saw the problem in your linked question, but how do you propose to solve it?  I think the macros Microsoft refers to in Office programs are keyboard/mouse macros, whereas all other uses of "macro" refer to language expansions.

Comment: I plan to go and review each question I can with both tags (also extends to related tags) retag if that's the only change needed, and suggest a more thorough edit if there's more work to be done. Call it my own personal crusade, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, but retag it to what?  Microsoft calls them "macros." Microsoft has never been great at naming things.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry for misunderstanding... VBA code is almost synonymous with 'macro', but the macro tag does not apply to this usage. In most cases, I expect to simply remove the macro tag. More to the point however, is that my question asks how much is too much in general, not just on this topic.

Comment: If you can get sufficient consensus here for the thing being fixed, there is no limit, other than the system-imposed limits of x number of suggestions per day.

Comment: Uh, what problem is this causing? As Robert says, MS calls them macros. It's all over in the UI. There's actually a ton of non-MS history behind that use too, if my DOS TSR flashbacks are at all accurate. And it's not like macros in C are the same as macros in Lisp; is removing them fixing some specific issue?

Comment: @Shog9 If you want to have that discussion, there's already more detail from me on the source question that I linked to. This question does not pertain to any specific tags/edits/issues. Yes, VBA code is often referred to as a macro, but the current macro tag does not describe this usage of the word. Perhaps you think an alternative answer to my other question would be to change the tag to be more inclusive of all possible uses?

Comment: @Shog9 I think what Gaffi means is that people are tagging their questions with [macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macro) when they really mean [VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba). Given the fuzzy nature of the distinction, there may be more important things to work on and Gaffi doesn't want to overwhelm the moderators with large amounts of suggested tag edits.

Comment: @JP: ok, that makes more sense - I've updated my answer to his other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In either case, is there any problem (or at the very least, annoyance) with taking it upon myself to go on an edit suggestion spree?

No, if your edits are useful and [comprehensive](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/). In particular, once you're submitting edits that need to be *approved*, you should go out of your way to either limit yourself to a subset of the posts being edited (*only* tags, *only* the title) or fix every problem everywhere - if a reviewer sees a post with a typo fixed in once place and not in another, rife with broken formatting and lousy grammar, then they're well within their rights to reject it... But when the edit produces a fine-looking post as the result, it's much easier to approve.

If your edits *don't* have to be approved, go ahead and make them. If you're planning on editing a large number of posts, look for some consensus here on Meta first (you've already started on this); once you start, just get it done. On Stack Overflow, you really don't have to worry about "flooding the front page" unless you're super-human.

Comment: That works for me - Main points are make good edits, and when en masse for a specific reason, come here first. Do I understand you, then?

Comment: Yup. Don't worry about the relative priority of one sort of cleanup over another - just make each action count for as much as you're able to.